# Leaflet api is not working Giving me error Request failed with status: 500

Tags: flutter, leaflet, http-status-code-500, google-search-api

Request failed with status: 500.

API url : https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1&query=cha

Working on this api but suddenly it stop working and stop giving me places list on search.

Anybody have any idea

I tried this also for limiting the requests

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      getSuggestion(destinationController.text);
      await Future.delayed(
          Duration(milliseconds: 400)); // Wait 4 milliseconds between each call
 }
```